# PHP error on posting index

Tags: php, indexing

Could you please help me solve this problem? I've been trying to post a content in a text box and try to display it using PHP 'echo' but it keeps displaying "Undefined index" and the content of the textbox is not posted. Here's the code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['updateaccount'])) {

$accountType = $_POST['typeBox'];

echo $accountType;
}
?>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<table>
<tr>
    <td><strong>Account Type<strong></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="typeBox" value="This is a test." disabled="true"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="updateaccount" value="Update Account"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Whenever I try to submit the form, it says:

Notice: Undefined index: typeBox in C:\xampp\htdocs\cel1rcfc\test.php on line 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you set the attribute `disabled="true"`, disabled input element will not be posted to the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You've marked the input as 'disabled':

```
<input type="text" name="typeBox" value="This is a test." disabled="true">
```

So it's not being submitted. However, the submit button (`updateaccount`) is enabled, so your check at the top passes.

Answer (score 0):

It is happing cause of u have set the attribut `disabled="true"` for text box remove `disabled="true"` to get the result u want to.

like this

```
<input type="text" name="typeBox" value="This is a test" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the attribute `disabled="true"` so that it will work.